# Problem with LaunchedEffect in composables of HorizontalPager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm creating a project with `Compose`, but I ran into a situation that I couldn't solve.

**View Model**:

```kotlin
data class OneState(
    val name: String = "",
    val city: String = ""
)

sealed class OneChannel {
    object FirstStepToSecondStep : OneChannel()
    object Finish : OneChannel()
}

@HiltViewModel
class OneViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    private val viewModelState = MutableStateFlow(OneState())
    val screenState = viewModelState.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.Eagerly,
        initialValue = viewModelState.value
    )

    private val _channel = Channel<OneChannel>()
    val channel = _channel.receiveAsFlow()

    fun changeName(value: String) {
        viewModelState.update { it.copy(name = value) }
    }

    fun changeCity(value: String) {
        viewModelState.update { it.copy(city = value) }
    }

    fun firstStepToSecondStep() {
        Log.d("OneViewModel", "start of method first step to second step")

        if (viewModelState.value.name.isBlank()) {
            Log.d("OneViewModel", "name is empty, nothing should be done")
            return
        }

        Log.d(
            "OneViewModel",
            "name is not empty, first step to second step event will be send for composable"
        )
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _channel.send(OneChannel.FirstStepToSecondStep)
        }
    }

    fun finish() {
        Log.d("OneViewModel", "start of method finish")

        if (viewModelState.value.city.isBlank()) {
            Log.d("OneViewModel", "city is empty, nothing should be done")
            return
        }

        Log.d(
            "OneViewModel",
            "city is not empty, finish event will be send for composable"
        )
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _channel.send(OneChannel.Finish)
        }
    }
}
```

This `ViewModel` has a `MutableStateFlow`, a `StateFlow` to be collected on `composable screens` and a `Channel`/`Flow` for "*one time events*".
The first two methods are to change a respective state and the last two methods are to validate some logic and then send an event through the `Channel`.

**Composables**:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun FirstStep(
    viewModel: OneViewModel,
    nextStep: () -> Unit
) {
    val state by viewModel.screenState.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        Log.d("FirstStep (Composable)", "start of launched effect block")

        viewModel.channel.collect { channel ->
            when (channel) {
                OneChannel.FirstStepToSecondStep -> {
                    Log.d("FirstStep (Composable)", "first step to second step action")
                    nextStep()
                }
                else -> Log.d(
                    "FirstStep (Composable)",
                    "another action that should be ignored in this scope"
                )
            }
        }
    }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(all = 16.dp),
            value = state.name,
            onValueChange = { viewModel.changeName(value = it) },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Type our name") }
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(weight = 1F))

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            onClick = { viewModel.firstStepToSecondStep() }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Next Step")
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SecondStep(
    viewModel: OneViewModel,
    prevStep: () -> Unit,
    finish: () -> Unit
) {
    val state by viewModel.screenState.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        Log.d("SecondStep (Composable)", "start of launched effect block")

        viewModel.channel.collect { channel ->
            when (channel) {
                OneChannel.Finish -> {
                    Log.d("SecondStep (Composable)", "finish action //todo")
                    finish()
                }
                else -> Log.d(
                    "SecondStep (Composable)",
                    "another action that should be ignored in this scope"
                )
            }
        }
    }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(all = 16.dp),
            value = state.city,
            onValueChange = { viewModel.changeCity(value = it) },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Type our city name") }
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(weight = 1F))

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(space = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(weight = 1F),
                onClick = prevStep
            ) {
                Text(text = "Previous Step")
            }

            Button(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(weight = 1F),
                onClick = { viewModel.finish() }
            ) {
                Text(text = "Finish")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun OneScreen(viewModel: OneViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)
    val pages = listOf<@Composable () -> Unit>(
        {
            FirstStep(
                viewModel = viewModel,
                nextStep = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(page = pagerState.currentPage + 1)
                    }
                }
            )
        },
        {
            SecondStep(
                viewModel = viewModel,
                prevStep = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(page = pagerState.currentPage - 1)
                    }
                },
                finish = {}
            )
        }
    )

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(weight = 1F),
            state = pagerState,
            count = pages.size,
            userScrollEnabled = false
        ) { index ->
            pages[index]()
        }

        HorizontalPagerIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
            pagerState = pagerState,
            activeColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
        )
    }
}
```

`OneScreen` has a `HorizontalPager` (from the *Accompanist library*) which receives two other composables, `FirstStep` and `SecondStep`, these two composables have their own `LaunchedEffect` to collect any possible event coming from the View Model.

Dependencies used:

```gradle
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.2'

implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.43.2'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.43.2'

implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.25.1'
implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.25.1'
```

The problem:
After typing something in the name field and clicking to go to the next step, the flow happens normally. When clicking to go back to the previous step, it also works normally. But now when clicking to go to the next step again, the `collect` in the `LaunchedEffect` of the `FirstStep` is not collected, instead the `collect` in `LaunchedEffect` of the `SecondStep` is, resulting in no action, and if click again, then `collect` in `FirstStep` works.

Some images that follow the logcat:

1. [when opening the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69EgK.png)
2. [after typing something and clicking to go to the next step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb9H8.png)
3. [going back to the first step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfrWN.png)
4. [clicking to go to next step (problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eUXJ.png)
5. [clicking for the second time (works)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFCge.png)

Comment: It seems to be a problem related to the way `HorizontalPager` handles the content. I did a test here replacing it with a `NavHost` and it worked normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `HorizontalPager` creates both the current page and the next page. When current page is `FirstStep`, both collectors are active and will be triggered sequentially.

Let's look at the three jump attempts on the first page. The first attempt is received by collector in `FirstStep` and successfully jumps to the second page. The second attempt is received by collector in `SecondStep` and fails. The third attempt succeeds again.

Actually, `HorizontalPager` is `LazyRow`, so this should be the result of `LazyLayout`'s place logic.

To solve this problem, I suggest merging the two `LaunchedEffect` and moving it into `OneScreen`. In fact, the viewmodel should all be moved to the top of the `OneScreen`, for cleaner code.

At last, here is my simplified code if you want try it.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Step(index: Int, flow: Flow<String>, onSwitch: () -> Unit, onSend: () -> Unit) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        println("LaunchEffect$index")
        flow.collect { println("Step$index:$it") }
    }
    Column {
        Text(text = index.toString(), style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3)
        Button(onClick = onSwitch) { Text(text = "Switch Page") }
        Button(onClick = onSend) { Text(text = "Send") }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val channel = remember { Channel<String>() }
    val flow = remember { channel.receiveAsFlow() }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    HorizontalPager(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        state = pagerState,
        count = 4,
        userScrollEnabled = false,
    ) { index ->
        Step(index = index, flow = flow,
            onSwitch = {
                scope.launch { pagerState.scrollToPage((index + 1) % pagerState.pageCount) }
            },
            onSend = {
                scope.launch { channel.send("Test") }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

If you keep click send button at first page, it will print:
[image]

Comment: I understood this point of `HorizontalPager`, I think that in my case it will be more interesting to use a `NavHost`/`AnimatedNavHost` then, since I didn't intend to let the user navigate between the "pages" with the scroll. About moving the ViewModel reference to the top, I will still analyze this possibility, because each "step" will have different type information, one with text fields, another with boxes to check and another to select images. Thanks for the information!